# I have to set a heading to the font-family "Cooper Black" but it never actually goes to it.

Tags: css

I'm submitting the gist I have of it with the questions as well. It is specifically question 8 on the full blown assignment. [This](https://gist.github.com/JStrong0037/67c1a09ccd1943be84f4) is the gist with all my code, but I used the line, font-family: 'Cooper Black', serif; which isn't working.

I feel pretty dumb that no matter what I've tried it never works for me. I've tried Chrome, Firefox, and Edge all three when opening this. I'm actually getting desperate to find the cause of the problem or what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for any help you guys can give me!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: Where are you including the Cooper Black font?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you given a webfont file with the assignment? If so, you need to import it using the @font-face rule, before using it in font-family. For example (it should be more complex than this, but usually webfonts provide you with a stylesheet that contains the exact code):

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Cooper Black";
  src: url("/fonts/cooper-black.otf");
}

.h1 {
  font-family: "Cooper Black", serif;
}
```

Otherwise, it should work if you have Cooper Black installed in your system.

More details at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I did some trouble shooting with the issue. Ubuntu won't load it at all for me, but on Windows 10 Chrome will do it every time. Edge is just inconsistent in general about if it'll load the file right at all though. I emailed the instructor with all of my work and he's going to check about the Firefox compatibility issues tomorrow. I'm just glad that I got it working correctly and consistently with Chrome so I know it works for sure now.

Comment: Despite not being web safe, is there any reason why some font's do not seem to work when specified in the font-family even when they are in the fonts of the client computer?